# How do i find the overcommit ratio for CPU on a KVM host or for that matter on any hypervisor?

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a host and I have installed KVM on it.Now I need to know how much overcommiting of resources it allows, CPU, memory. Is there some command to get the ratios or it all exists in theory and no official documentation exists for it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVM is just the hypervisor itself. It allows overcommitment without any artificial limit.

The limits are provided by any management tools installed on top of KVM, such as OpenStack.